# How to navigate the parse tree when the scraped content doesn't match the web page content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the data of the players table for my own personal use on this link:
https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats

However, no matter how I try to navigate the parse tree, I can never seem to access the actual table statistics part of the html for the players.

[Web page html for player stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N4Mm.png)

The *id* tag in the web page for the table is *id="div_stats_standard"*. When I look for this in the soup in my Jupyter Notebook code using the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all(id= "div_stats_standard")
print(table)
```

I get the output:

```
[]
```

Even stranger, when I scroll down through the soup in my code to the part where the tag exists in the web page html, it's not there?? I have it marked out where the *id* tag should be in the image below. Can anyone help me with this please?

[Web scraping code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK5w4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can obtain the tables on that page (I imagine the one you're looking for is the last dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

url= 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats'
response = requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
dfs = pd.read_html(response)
for df in dfs:
    print(df)
```

This will return the available tables on the page:

```
Squad   # Pl    Age Poss    MP  Starts  Min 90s Gls Ast G-PK    PK  PKatt   CrdY    CrdR    Gls Ast G+A G-PK    G+A-PK  xG  npxG    xA  npxG+xA xG  xA  xG+xA   npxG    npxG+xA
0   Arsenal 16  24.6    51.0    3   33  270 3.0 8   6   8   0   0   4   0   2.67    2.00    4.67    2.67    4.67    5.4 5.4 3.1 8.5 1.80    1.04    2.83    1.80    2.83
1   Aston Villa 18  26.8    57.7    3   33  270 3.0 3   3   3   0   0   8   0   1.00    1.00    2.00    1.00    2.00    3.5 3.5 2.9 6.4 1.17    0.97    2.14    1.17    2.14
2   Bournemouth 18  26.2    36.3    3   33  270 3.0 2   1   2   0   0   8   0   0.67    0.33    1.00    0.67    1.00    0.9 0.9 0.5 1.5 0.30    0.18    0.48    0.30    0.48
3   Brentford   19  26.2    44.7    3   33  270 3.0 8   6   8   0   0   2   0   2.67    2.00    4.67    2.67    4.67    3.7 3.7 3.0 6.8 1.24    1.01    2.25    1.24    2.25
4   Brighton    17  28.0    47.7    3   33  270 3.0 4   2   3   1   1   3   0   1.33    0.67    2.00    1.00    1.67    2.6 2.6 1.9 4.5 0.86    0.64    1.50    0.86    1.50
5   Chelsea 17  28.1    62.3    3   33  270 3.0 3   2   2   1   1   8   1   1.00    0.67    1.67    0.67    1.33    3.1 2.3 1.9 4.3 1.02    0.64    1.66    0.78    1.42
[...]
```

Comment: Wow that works perfectly, thank you! I was wondering if you could help me understand your solution a little better. I don't even see where you've used the BeautifulSoup library, although I know you did because I had to install the lxml package into my environment to get it to work. Do you know why the lxml package is necessary here?

Comment: @user101 actually that bs4 import (beautifulSoup) was redundant: parsing was performed by pandas. Your table of interest is table #3 (and the last one on that page). Pandas probably requires lxml, although it should fall back on bs4/html.parser if you don't have it installed. pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html Oh, and if my answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted (green checkmark under voting buttons).

Comment: Okay, great. Also, if you don't mind me asking, I noticed the html comment marks when inspecting the web page but was confused why they were appearing in the soup differently. Is this something the web developer did to make scraping more difficult or was it an issue with the BeautifulSoup parser?